# How do I texture paint symmetrically in blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Where is symmetry setting in texture painting in blender 2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3D View *N* panel > *Symmetry*, or in the Properties panel > *Active Tool* > *Symmetry*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. for your help